# How to uninstall GRUB

Tags: arch-linux, grub

I just installed Arch Linux and it's not working well, and now I can't access Windows because of GRUB. How can I uninstall GRUB through the Arch Linux shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot 'uninstall' grub. You can overwrite it by Windows bootloader. I'm afraid that most people who know how to reinstall Windows bootloader without reinstalling Windows are on superuser (I guess for most people here Windows is the second system) - you have to do it from Windows install disk or similar tools.

You should be able to chainload the Windows bootloader from grub by following code BTW:

```
title Windows
    rootnoverify (hd0,0)
    chainloader +1
```

or entering commandline in GRUB

```
rootnoverify (hd0,0)
chainloader +1
```

PS. What is not working well? It is part we can help with. Have you tried simpler distributions like for example Ubuntu?

Comment: Some Linux installers save the original boot sector, so they can restore it. That does assume you can at least boot your new system.

Comment: @Gilles: I don't think non-user-friendly installers (read Arch, Debian etc) do that. Anyway there is mention of Arch Linux shell and recent questions about Arch so bootability of Arch seems to be reasonable assumption.

Comment: @Maciej: I can't even find one on Ubuntu. Though maybe it's because it's not a dual boot.

Comment: @Gilles: I cannot recall stating that Ubuntu do save. I stated that I guess that Arch's and Debian's don't.

Comment: @Maciej: I don't recall you stating that either. I thought I'd seen a distribution do it, and given my habits and environment it would probably be Debian or Ubuntu. Maybe I made this up from whole cloth.

Comment: @Maciej- I tried modifying the GRUB file as you mentioned but that takes me to a restore session and I can't go anywhere from there!! 

THe problem I faced in Arch Linux is that I couldn't get pacman working(probably due to network issues??)!

Comment: @infoquad: As of pacman - that's probably separate question. As of restore session - if it boots it seems that Windows bootloader is working. Try next partition (sometimes `(hd0,0)` is restore and you need `(hd0,1)`) - if it won't help I'm afraid that it's windows-side problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to get rid of the dual boot in my work computer (needed space for work stuff) and I used the MBRFix utility which you can download here:

http://www.sysint.no/products/Download/tabid/536/language/en-US/Default.aspx